# How to get modified item details inside ngFor trackBy?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Suppose I have an array of objects having 10 items which are tracked for changes using trackBy. After few seconds lets say 3rd item has been changed and only 3rd item is re rendered in DOM. Now I  would like to get/track that **3rd object alone** which is modified after few seconds. Is it possible ?

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of array; trackBy: trackByFunction">
      {{item.name}}
  </div>

  trackByFunction(index,item){
    if(!item) return null;
    return item.id;
  }
```

Comment: You can get this done using by saving changed state by yourself separately.